# Can i put a formula in an IF THEN Else statement?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

In the linked table, I would like to populate column H with a formula.  The formula to be used is dependent on the value in column F.  Each day, the number of rows and the number of possible values in column F can change.  I thought vba would be the best approach to set this up but I'm having trouble with the code. Would this even be the way to start the code?

```
Sub Macro4()
Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Label = Range("F2") = "AUD/JPY"
```

[image: Table]

Comment: I am not sure what the output should be? You can have a formula in an if then else but it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. It feels like you' re looking for something like `SELECT CASE`, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: `Label = Range("F2") = "AUD/JPY"` will need to split into two lines `Label =  "AUD/JPY"` and `Range("F2") = Label`.  Don't forget to declare Label as a String

Comment: The output is the result of the formula which is an If statement.  It will say whether or not the option should be exercised based upon the current price that is pulled in column G.  That is why I thought an if than else statement would be best.

Answer (score 0):

I made up formulas for column H, but you should be able to apply this pattern with whatever formulas you need entered.

```
Sub Macro4()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim xCell As Range
    lastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each xCell In Range(ActiveSheet.Range("F2"), ActiveSheet.Range("F2").End(xlDown))
        Select Case xCell.Value
        Case "AUD/JPY"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(xCell.Row, "H").Formula = "=G" & xCell.Row & "/E" & xCell.Row
        Case "AUD/USD"
             ActiveSheet.Cells(xCell.Row, "H").Formula = "=2*G2"
        '''Case etc... write other cases you need to handle
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```